# Не срабатывает successful_payment в aiogram 3

Tags: aiogram

Платёж высылается, оплата проходит успешно, но никакого моего события после успешной оплаты не происходит, помогите найти ошибку
Вот часть кода:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart




@dp.message(CommandStart)
async def buy(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id,
                           title='Билет',
                           description='Билет',
                           payload='s',
                           provider_token=PAYMENT_TOKEN,
                           currency='RUB',
                           start_parameter='CHTO',
                           prices=[{'label':'Руб','amount':15000}])

#Обработка платежа срабатывает
@dp.pre_checkout_query(lambda query: True)
async def pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q: types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q.id, ok=True)



#Эта часть кода просто не срабатывает
@dp.message(F.successful_payment)
async def successful_payment(message: types.Message):
    msg = 'Спасибо за покупку'
    await message.answer(msg)



async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста, удалось ли решить проблему?